# How do I compile a project with multiple source files?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I have a main code (`.cpp`) and some other files (`.cpp` and their corresponding `.h` file) which contain the function that are used in my main program. I'd like to know how to compile my files and run the main code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on your compiler. For example, with GCC you might write:

```
g++ foo.cpp bar.cpp baz.cpp -o foo # compile program
./foo                              # run program
```

Comment: I mention -Wall & -g which are very useful.

Comment: we can also use this command to compile all files in a folder: g++ *.cpp

Comment: On a Mac, `g++` actually points to `clang`. Doing the above generates the error message `clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`

Answer (score 6):

[Basile's right on, you need *build machinery*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513834/377270) to have software you can easily work on. You *really* want to be able to just run `make` or something similar and get your project re-built quickly in a repeatable fashion. You also want to make sure that your entire project is kept up to date, rebuilding everything that depends upon something that has changed. While you could just keep around a shell script containing `g++` lines as in [ruakh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513376/377270), this will needlessly recompile more than you need. (Which isn't a big deal with small projects but becomes important when projects grow larger than trivial.)

I've only taken fifteen minutes to skim the OMake documentation, but it looks very promising. `make` is standard on systems and provides a huge array of pre-defined build rules, including rules for C++, so it isn't very difficult to write new `Makefile`s for projects.

It'll look something like this:

```
# the compiler and its flags
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

PROGRAM = foo

OBJECTS = foo_a.o foo_b.o foo_c.o foo_d.o

.PHONY: all

.DEFAULT: all

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS)
```

The objects `foo_a.o` will be built from a corresponding source file named `foo_a.c`, `foo_a.cc`, `foo_a.C`, `foo_a.cpp`, `foo_a.p`, `foo_a.f`, `foo_a.F`, etc., for C, C++, Fortran, Pascal, Lex, Yacc, and so on.

The [O'Reilly `make` book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780937175903.do) is sadly quite dated at this point; the `.SUFFIX` rules have been supplanted by [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), but there is no coverage of pattern rules in the O'Reilly book. That said, it is still a good starting point if the full [GNU Make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/make.html#Top) isn't a good fit for you.

Comment: I added `CXXFLAGS` & `CXX` in your example `Makefile`

Comment: Thanks Basile! I do like the GNU Make documentation for looking up specific things, but I must admit I didn't wade my way through the GNU documentation until _after_ making it all the way through the O'Reilly book first.

Answer (score 1):

But the real answer is to use some build machinery, like e.g. have a [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) and use [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/).

There are some better builder than GNU Make, like [Omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html)

Builders are very useful, because in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513376/841108) by *ruakh* you may don't want to recompile `foo.cpp` when only `bar.cpp` changed so you need to take dependencies into account.

(and there are *Makefile* generators, like `automake`, `cmake` ...)